# Fuse/Camel: How to stop after downloading just one file

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

Fuse/Camel newbie here.  I'm trying to automate a manual process where `.done` files are downloaded from an FTP host, then renamed `"fileout.txt"`, and finally an AS/400 program is executed on that file.

However, the department hosting the `AS/400` program doesn't have resources to update their programming.  The solution I'm working toward is to have Camel download one file at a time, save it as `"fileout.txt"`, then execute a JT400 program to process it.  Individually those steps work but I'm left with one problem.

What I pray you, dear reader, can help me with is **"How can I stop Camel after downloading just one file?** 
(since overwriting, appending, or downloading multiple files won't work for the following step)".

Comment: Could you add what you have tried so far and be more specific with what you are trying to ask for.

Comment: Tried using fileexists=fail to write one and cancel out the rest, but that doesn't get the file to leave the FTP.  Tried figuring out a regular expression for selecting just one file, but I don't think they can compare from file to file.  Tried figuring out seda to sequence, but I'm not sure that fits the need and it's not making much sense to me at first blush.

Comment: By goodness, that worked.  Thank you HK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I stop Camel after downloading just one file?

You can set following parameters in FTP consumer

- `maxMessagesPerPoll=1` (Limit number of message to be download in single batch)
- `delay=500000` (Increase the time interval between each poll, so you have time to stop the route)

Then, your ftp route can trigger an asynchronous message (maybe [wireTap component](https://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html)) to another route to trigger [controlBus component](http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html) to stop the ftp route by route id.

> I'm trying to automate a manual process where `.done` files are downloaded from an FTP host, then renamed `fileout.txt`, and finally an AS/400 program is executed on that file

Other than stop/start your route, you may try [pollEnrich component](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) with FTP usage. Using pollEnrich, you can trigger FTP consumer once when needed if you know the target file name already.